# Delete file from diff directory every time

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my case i have 4 diff directory. (Week_1, Week_2, Week_3, Week_4)

The last number (1,2,3,4) already exist in another bat file. LastFolder.bat

I want a batch script to read the LastFolder.bat then go to a specific directory and delete all files in the directory. Not the directory only the files

PS: The LastFolder.bat has only a number from 1 to 4 nothing else

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%a in (lastfolder.bat) do set /a target=%%a
echo(del Week_%target%\*?*
```

This should do the task.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.